# Submit form on select change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/47apf/

It should submit the form on select change but it doesnt do anything

```
$(function() {
    $('#candidate_filter').change(function() {
        this.form.submit();
    });
});
```

Can anyone please explain why this code doesn't work?

Comment: this is already the form. try this.submit();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you don't need the `.form` in this case.

```
$(function() {
  $('#candidate_filter').change(function() {
    this.submit();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Here, `this` itself is the form.

Write this:

```
$('#candidate_filter').change(function() {
    $(this).trigger('submit');
});
```

Updated [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/47apf/1/) here.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$('#candidate_filter').change(function() {
        //alert("hii");
        this.submit();
    });
```

**Fiddle:** [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sid_m/47apf/4/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign id of drop down as below:

```
    <form id="candidate_filter">
    <select name="vacancy" id="candidate_filter1">
    <option value="all">Any Vacancy</option>
    <option value="1">Engineering lk;lk;</option>
    </select>
    <select name="status" id="candidate_filter2">
    <option value="all">Any Status</option>
    <option value="open">Open for applications</option>
    <option value="closed">Closed for applications</option>
    <option value="inactive">Inactive</option>
    </select>
    <select name="date">
    <option value="all">Any Date</option>
    <option value="today">Today</option>
    <option value="3">3 days</option>
    <option value="7">This week</option>
    </select>
    <select name="consideration" id="candidate_filter3">
    <option value="all">Any Consideration</option>
    <option value="qualified">Qualified</option>
    <option value="rejected">Rejected</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

JS

```
    $(function() {
        $('select[id^="candidate_filter"]').change(function() {
            this.form.submit();
        });
    });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/47apf/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to submit the form like this:  `$('#candidate_filter').submit();`

Here is a working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/47apf/5/

**JQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $('#candidate_filter').change(function() {
        alert("change event catched");
         $('#candidate_filter').submit();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this in jQuery.

Put a class on your **select**, and bind the event **onchange**

```
 $('.candidateList').on('change', function(evt){
    $('#candidate_filter').submit();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/darksioul/4ygAg/2/

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(function() {
    $('#candidate_filter select[name="vacancy"]').change(function() {
        $('#candidate_filter').submit();
    });
});
```

Inside jQuery selectors, the **this** word references to the selected element on DOM, in you original code, $('#candidate_filter') represents the FORM element. Adding a second reference you have a better approach to what you desire $('#candidate_filter select[name="vacancy"]'). And to submit the form, you need to point especifically to the FORM element.